# Solve the sytem of differential equations, using Euler's method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, differential

Using Euler's method (the method of eigenvalues and eigenvectors, the case of
different complex eigenvalues) solve the sytem of differential equations $\overrightarrow{y'}$ = A$\overrightarrow{y}$ or solve the
initial value problem $\overrightarrow{y'}$= A$\overrightarrow{y}$, $\overrightarrow{y}$(0) = $\overrightarrow{y}_0$, if

\begin{bmatrix}-7&1\\-2&−5\end{bmatrix}

**My attempt**: (but unfortunately it is not Euler's method, i don't understand this method):

So i have started from forming a new matrix by subtracting $λ$ from the diagonal entries of the given matrix:\begin{bmatrix}−λ-7&1\\-2&−λ−5\end{bmatrix}
The determinant of the obtained matrix is $λ_2+12λ+37$

Solve the equation $λ^2+12λ+37=0.$

The roots are $λ1=−6−i, λ2=−6+i$, these are the eigenvalues.

Next, i have found the eigenvectors.

- $λ=−6−i$

$\begin{bmatrix}−λ-7&1\\-2&−λ−5\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}−1+i&1\\-2&i+1\end{bmatrix}$

The null space of this matrix is $\begin{bmatrix}1/2+i/2\\  1\end{bmatrix}$,

This is the eigenvector.

- $λ=−6+i$

$\begin{bmatrix}−λ-7&1\\-2&−λ−5\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}−1+i&1\\-2&i-1\end{bmatrix}$,

The null space of this matrix is $\begin{bmatrix}1/2-i/2\\  1\end{bmatrix}$,

and this is the eigenvector.

**And i dont know what i should do next to calculate the fundamental equations (formula) or any other solution is of the following form.**

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For linear homogeneous differential equations we have the following observation. If $z \in \mathbb{C}$ is a solution to the differential, then we know that the real and imaginary part for $z$ are also solutions to the differential equation.

Hence, calculate the complex solution first. Then determine the real and imaginary part of your base solutions you should be able to extract two independent solutions from this step.

Answer (score -1):

For every pair of complex eigenvalues $p\pm qi$ your solutions get a component of the form $e^{px}(a\cos qx + b\sin qx)$. In your case they look as:  $y_{k}=e^{-6x}(a_k\cos x + b_k\sin x)$ where $k\in (1,2)$. The two sets of constants $a_k,b_k$ can be figured out from the system's matrix and the boundary conditions.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).